# How long label (spread on multiple lines) of the HTML checkbox input can be aligned with the start of the label on the first line?

Tags: html, css

This checkbox is HTML input of type checkbox. Its picture and HTML is given below.

```html
<div id="div123" style="word-wrap:break-word;">
 <input tabindex="5" enterastab="" type="checkbox" id="chkBx" name="v_108950" value="OPTION_1111111111111"/>
 <label id="lbl123" for="chkBx" unselectable="on">Option 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</label>
</div>
```

[image]

**Question:** When the labels are too long, how can I make the label printed on next lines start right below the "O" instead of starting from the left side of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a 2-column layout with Flexbox

```css
#div123 {
  /* Create a flexible container with the display property */
  /* A flexible container will create a separate column for each of its children, here a checkbox and a label */
  display: flex;
  
  /* align-items decide how to align the columns vertically */
  /* with flex-start, the checkbox and the label will be align to the top */
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div id="div123">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkBx" name="v_108950" value="OPTION_1111111111111" />
  <label id="lbl123" for="chkBx" unselectable="on">Option 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flexbox and set `display: flex` on parent div element. Also you can add `word-break: break-all` on label but you also need to add `br` after first word so that numbers appear under option.

```css
div {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: flex-start;
}
label {
  word-break: break-all; 
}
```

```html
<div id="div123">
  <input tabindex="5" enterastab="" type="checkbox" id="chkBx" name="v_108950" value="OPTION_1111111111111" />
  <label id="lbl123"  for="chkBx" unselectable="on">Option <br> 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline-block property here or float property

```
input {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}


label {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```